# How to show that context-free languages are closed by the full-shuffle operation?

Tags: closed-form, automata, context-free-grammar

Let be the full-shuffle operation, $S(L_1,L_2)=\{w|w=w_1w_2...w_k\mbox{ such that $w_{2k+1}\in L_1$ and  $w_{2k}\in L_2$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$}\}$. That is to say the language $L$ that contains the words which we can build from a word from $L_1$, followed by a word from $L_2$, followed by a word from $L_1$, etc...

#### How to show that context-free languages are closed by this operation ?

#### My attempt

Let be two grammars which variables are disjoint and whichi initial variables are $S_1$ and $S_2$. We take the grammar which have a new initial variable $S$.

$$S\rightarrow \varepsilon | S_1|S_2$$
$$S_1\rightarrow DS_1 $$
$$S_2\rightarrow DS_2 $$
$$DS_1\rightarrow DS_1S_2 $$
$$DS_2\rightarrow DS_2S_1 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205025/are-regular-languages-closed-by-a-full-shuffle-operation), there is a small ambiguity in the definition since you do not specify whether $k$ should be even. Anyway, if you assume that $k$ is even, then
$S(L_1,L_2) = (L_1L_2)^*$ and if there is no restriction on $k$, then
$S(L_1,L_2) = (L_1L_2)^* \cup (L_1L_2)^*L_1$.

In both cases, if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are regular, then $S(L_1,L_2)$ is regular (which answers your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205025/are-regular-languages-closed-by-a-full-shuffle-operation), and if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are context-free, then $S(L_1,L_2)$ is context-free, since regular [respectively context-free] languages are closed under union, product and star.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Yet, even if I understand what you wrote. We use to use a system with arrow to display these grammar. For instance :

\begin{align*}
P &→ N P_v\\
P &→ P \mbox{ and } P\\
P_v&→ V\\
P_V&→ V N\\
N& → Francois\\
N&→ Nicolas\\
N&→ Marine\\
V&→ loves\\
V&→ hates\\
V&→ run\\
\end{align*}

It allows to represent phrases like this : $P$ is a full sentence, $P_v$ is the verbal part. $N$ is the noun and $V$ is the verb. 
For our case, would it be :
\begin{align}
S\rightarrow(L_1&L_2)^*\bigcup(L_1L_2)^*L_1
\end{align}

Comment: And $k\in \mathbb{N}$ only, no other restrictions...